# render status: 200 with background jobs like sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, sidekiq

I am dealing with Shopify order creation webhooks and it is triggering multiple times.

```
def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
    found = false
    order_item_ids = []
    webhook['line_items'].each do |line_item|
        line_item['properties'].each do |property|
            if property['name'] == 'BJ_PROD'
                found = true
                order_item_ids << line_item['product_id']
            end
        end
    end
    if found
        @order = Order.create({
          shop: shop,
          shopify_order_id: webhook["id"],
          status: 'Ordered',
          sent_to_admin: false,
          order_details: webhook
        })
    end

    session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shop.shopify_domain, shop.shopify_token)
    session = ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
    order_item_ids.each do |order_item_id|
      product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(order_item_id)
      product.published_at = nil
      product.save!
    end
    shop.with_shopify_session do
    end
    render status: 200, json: @order.to_json
  end
```

I am trying to use **render status: 200** and **head :ok** in my OrdersCreateJob class but it is giving error as it is being used in the background job.
Does anybody have an idea of how to deal with such scenarios?

Comment: What kind of error is receiving?

Comment: Background jobs do not occur in a controller / request context. They happen in the *background*. Therefore `render` is not available. You need to render in the controller where the job is being queued.